# EditText lineSpacingExtra strange behavior

Tags: android, android-edittext, line, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an EditText with lineSpacingExtra set to 8dp. When I open a page with this EditText and preset text, the line spacing works well. But when at the same page I click on the end of the EditText and start typing, the line spacing seems to be ignored.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Added code snippet. There's nothing special about it, I think.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="8dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dip"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        />
```

update: Looks like the bug came with the **Android 5** Lollipop

Comment: Maybe is better if you post your layout code, so we can check what you have set!

Comment: looks like a bug has already been posted: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78706

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @BartBergmans there were several workarounds in the bug report proposed by others, but they all lead to various glitches, so I just removed line spacing for the time being.

Comment: Here's the workaround I found; it's very crude but it seems to work for me: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78706#c17

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug, that has been posted: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37009353 , I find a fix method:this bug occur only when you inputing in the last line, so you can aways append a blank line on the last.

Answer (score 0):

I share my code. Kotlin.

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    val added = count - before > 0 // blocking EditText#setText() when user remove text

    val startChar = if (start > 0) s[start - 1] else null
    if (startChar == '\n' && added) {
        val selectionStart = editText.selectionStart
        editText.setText(s)
        editText.setSelection(selectionStart)
    }
}
```